# After movement, do theta roles stay the same after wh-movement and verb raising?

Tags: syntax-trees, questions, theta-role

The example sentence is "Which purse has Lena bought?" which stems from the statement "Lena has bought which purse". Do the theta roles that bought assigns stay the same after the movement to create a question?

Comment: Do you want them to? It's a matter of definition, and you can use whichever you like.

Comment: Why would they change?